# Add indicators automatically to bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap carousel in example as youu see and I don't want to add indicators in html I just want to add in js to work for every carousel and I found a function on the internet and it's work very well but it's work just for one carousel

I have two carousel `#carousel-1` and `#carousel-2` but my function work is just for `#carousel-1`.I know if I give same class my problem will be solved but carousel id and `li.data-target` of indicators must be same.

How can I add `carousel-indicators` automatically with js to see their indicators ?

```js
  var myCarousel = $("#carousel-1");
  myCarousel.append("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>");
  var indicators = $(".carousel-indicators"); 
  myCarousel.find(".carousel-inner").children(".item").each(function(index) {
      (index === 0) ? 
      indicators.append("<li data-target='#carousel-1' data-slide-to='"+index+"' class='active'></li>") : 
      indicators.append("<li data-target='#carousel-1' data-slide-to='"+index+"'></li>");
  });     

$('.carousel').carousel();
```

```css
.carousel{
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>SLİDER 1</h1>

    <!-- SLIDER 1-->
    <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/26/02/13/bishan-1931390_960_720.jpg" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/26/15/34/simplicity-1932331_960_720.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    <!-- SLIDER 1 END-->
    
    <h1>SLİDER 2</h1>
    
    <!-- SLIDER 2-->
    <div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/26/02/13/bishan-1931390_960_720.jpg" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/26/15/34/simplicity-1932331_960_720.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    <!-- SLIDER 2 END-->
    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it dynamic this way. This solution will work in any number of carousel you have without any changes :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var myCarousels = $(".carousel");
    myCarousels.each(function( index, element  ) {
        var myCarousel = $("#"+$(element).attr('id')); 
        myCarousel.append("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>");
        var indicators = $("#"+$(element).attr('id') + " .carousel-indicators"); 
        $("#"+$(element).attr('id') +" .carousel-inner").children(".item").each(function(index) {
            console.log(index);
            (index === 0) ? 
            indicators.append("<li data-target='#"+$(element).attr('id')+"' data-slide-to='"+index+"' class='active'></li>") : 
            indicators.append("<li data-target='#"+$(element).attr('id')+"' data-slide-to='"+index+"'></li>");
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/98L5Lu4p/1/

Comment: Your solution works partially; the indicators don't seem to change active state...

Comment: yea, it looks like they are being created dynamically so for bootstrap they've never existed! any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
function appendIndicator(carousel)
{
  var myCarousel = $(carousel);
    myCarousel.append("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>");
    var indicators = $(".carousel-indicators"); 
    myCarousel.find(".carousel-inner").children(".item").each(function(index) {
        (index === 0) ? 
        indicators.append("<li data-target='"+ carousel +"' data-slide-to='"+index+"' class='active'></li>") : 
        indicators.append("<li data-target='" + carousel + "' data-slide-to='"+index+"'></li>");
    });     
}

$('.carousel').carousel();

appendIndicator('#carousel-1');
appendIndicator('#carousel-2');
```

[Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5b0mw0a/)