# Bootstrap > Carousel > number of Indicators needs to match the images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a Carousel Slider and I made it work using Bootstrap + Advanced Custom Fields.
Everything is working just fine however I can't figure out how to make the Indicators match the number of images I have. Since it's written individually for each image.
I am not good with JS which is why I took this approach using Bootstrap. As for ACF I am using Repeater and a sub field of Image (even do I called it a gallery ;) )

Help would be appriciated.

```css
some CSS code here
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
    
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
    
            <?php
            if( have_rows('aa-gallery') ):
                $count = 0;
                while ( have_rows('aa-gallery') ) : the_row();
                ?>
                    <div class="item <?php if (!$count) {
                    ?>active<?php 
                  } ?>">
                        <img src="<? the_sub_field('aa-gpic');?> " alt="<? the_sub_field('aa-caption');?>" style="width: 100%;">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php the_sub_field('aa-caption'); ?>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?
                    
            $count++;
                endwhile;
            
            else :
            
                // no rows found
            
            endif;
            
            ?>
          </div>
    
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
    
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use PHP for the indicators in exactly the same way you use it for listing the cariousel items themselves:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <?php if( have_rows('aa-gallery') ): ?>
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <?php
              $count = 0;
              while ( have_rows('aa-gallery') ) : the_row();
            ?>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $count; ?>" class="<?php if (!$count) {
                      ?>active<?php 
                    } ?>"></li>
            <?php
              $count++;
              endwhile;
            ?>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">

              <?php
                  $count = 0;
                  while ( have_rows('aa-gallery') ) : the_row();
                  ?>
                      <div class="item <?php if (!$count) {
                      ?>active<?php 
                    } ?>">
                          <img src="<? the_sub_field('aa-gpic');?> " alt="<? the_sub_field('aa-caption');?>" style="width: 100%;">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">
                                  <h3>
                                      <?php the_sub_field('aa-caption'); ?>
                                  </h3>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      <?

              $count++;
              endwhile;
              ?>
            </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

For a more elegant solution in JS, before you initialize the slider, you should count the number of items, and then populate the indicator-list with the matching amount of elements. But the above code should also work well enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works wonderfully. If it's possible could you write your other solution. It would be a nice practive for me to see how to do it in JS. Since I have 0 knowledge on how to use it.
Regardless I marked your answer as the acceptable one since it good enough.

So thank you :)

Comment: I've found this answer in a previous question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395449/11724378  - It seems to work well, according to the fiddle. You just need to remove the current <ol> part entirely from the HTML.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to play around with the code and see how to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the solution. But the active class don't change for the indicator.